# Is rowhammer comparable to faults caused by radiation?

Tags: attacks, memory, rowhammer

As far as I know, both rowhammer and radiation based fault injection, can cause arbitrary bit flips in the memory.

Are there any differences in matters of possible outcomes of both "attacks" on common hardware?

---

EDIT: In order to specify my question a bit: Could rowhammer cause control flow errors like usual fault injection does?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the principle and impact is the same. One of the specific properties of Rowhammer is that it is affecting nearby memory rows only (hence the name **row**hammer). This makes establishing non-destructive attacks a challenge.